# dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new': permission denied

Tags: command-line, dpkg, 64-bit

I am new to Linux. I have downloaded a virtualbox and am using a virtual version of linux (ubuntu 64-bit) on a windows PC. I am following [this guide](https://kivyspacegame.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/tutorial-how-to-build-python-for-android-with-ubuntu-and-buildozer/) to make an apk using kivy. One of the steps is to run `dpkg --add-architecture i386` in the terminal. Upon doing this, i get the error:

`dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new': Permission denied`

Having searched the web for fixes to this message, I tried to run this with `sudo` in front, but this doesn't seem to do anything. I tried to remove the lock file using `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`, but this also didn't return anything.

What am I doing wrong, and how should I correct it?

Edit:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release 18.04
Codename: bionic
```

Comment: which release? `lsb_release -a` please? edit your question for that.

Comment: Think that guide is some what outdated, dont think newer version need that i386 step.

Comment: @nobody updated

Comment: @bac0n do you know if the rest of the steps in the guide will still be ok? if not, where can I find another guide?